# How to design an enterprise application with many independent processes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture, jmx

How should I design an application comprised of numerous (but identical) **independent** processes that need to communicate data to an enterprise application and be monitored and accessible by a web interface?

Here's a more concrete example in Java:

1. The independent processes are multiple instances of a standalone J2SE application that receives on initialization data about a "user" entity and then starts doing stuff regarding this "user" (this is an infinite process and so any batch sort of design would be wrong here and also similarly, the starting time of these processes is irrelevant)
2. The enterprise application is a set of J2EE beans and web-services that implement business logic, DB access etc.. and that are (for example) hosted on GlassFish.
3. The web front is a set of JSPs (perhaps also on GlassFish) that work with the beans.

Now ideally, I want a way for the processes in (1) to be able to invoke methods from the beans in (2), but **also** for the beans in (2) to be able and update the processes (1) about things.

So these are the required flows of executions, assuming there are 10 independent process of (1) running for 10 different users (consider a "user" something easily identifiable by, say, a number):

- Something happens in one of the processes of (1) and they invoke a method from the enterprise application (2) with some data.
- One of the real, human, users (which was already identified by the web app) clicks something on a web-page of (3), this invokes a method in (2), and then some "magical" entity (which I have no idea how to name) finds the independent process from (1) that is responsible for this particular user and updates the process with some new data.

My best approach so far is to expose these J2SE apps by JMX and go from there, but I have one thing I don't understand - who or what should be holding a key-pair list of the sort "the process at URI **X** is responsible for user **Y**" and then directing the calls accordingly.

BTW, please feel free to give any advice outside of the Java platform (!), as long as it is a platform that can be scaled easily.

**EDIT:**
Also, is there a way to "host" such independent processes on some app-server? Something that will re-spawn processes if they fail, allow for deployment and monitoring of such processes on remote machines etc.?

Comment: Can't you use JMS ? When someone clicks from the admin GUI a message is going to be published that includes the userID. Clients will listen for messages and if the id concerns them, then they can act. Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: This is good and simple advice! This does incur quite some overhead, though, since the updates from the enterprise application (2) to the processes (1) can be quite large. But perhaps if the message sent is only "user #8 changed" and then the process concerned with user #8 **pulls** the complete data from (2) this could work. What do you think? A main concern, aside from feasibility, is the scaling up of this solution, please comment your opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some time since I have used Java Message Service in the past so I am afraid I am not up-to-date with the technical details, but from your description it seems like it would suit your case, to handle communication between the adminstration GUI and the client processes.

There are various options (I believe you are interested for asynchronous communication) so you should take a look on the latest developments to examine yourself if it fits your case or not.

Regarding the data size that the server would exchange with the processes I believe this is a different topic and I must say that the answer depends. Would it be better to send all data in the message? Or would the message be just a notification so the client to be notified and then connect to some enterprise bean to check some new state? I would prefer the latter case but this is something you should decide based on your requirements. I wouldn't blindly exclude the first option unless I had some apparent evidence that this wouldn't work.

Regarding the scaling I don't think it can be much worse then the scaling of your rest of your beans. As much the server is concerned they processes are all clients that need to be served.

Please take the above advice with a grain of salt: I don't know specifics of your problem/design. I am speaking more about in a general way.

I hope that helps

Comment: This advice was good and was my chosen way of implementation (specifically, I decided to go for a solution where broadcasted messages are small and the large data is then pulled by request). However, the answer still lacks a response for my edit.

Comment: @Stav sorry I missed your edit since the system notifies me only if you mention my nick i.e. in a comment or if you leave a comment to an answer of mine (as you did now). So you now want to convert your J2SE standalone independent processes to run in a J2EE remote server (i.e. not the same host where 2. is)? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: that's almost exactly what I want. Theoretically, I don't mind the independent processes to continue running as J2SE on remote JVMs but I don't want to build an entire mechanism my self for monitoring them, starting/stopping and restarting in terms of failure. Thx.

Comment: @Stav hmmm I am afraid I am not aware of an out-of the box solution that will deploy/re-spawn processes for you. I was more thinking of a custom solution but you say you want to avoid it. Perhaps you could use JMX (if you are not already using it), but my knowledge is limited on that area :(